# Distribute ios app to selected devices without paying for developer program

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 10.1 and I am trying to allow a third party to test the app I have built but don't want to pay for the developer program.

I saw https://www.diawi.com/ but I can't see how to generate a `.IPA` file for diawi.

I followed the instructions for [Fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/beta-walkthrough.html) but it doesn't auto-detect the product archive file `.xarchive`.

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't distribute your app to third person without paid apple account. Because you need to add that third person's device's UDID on your apple account and generate new certificates. So yeah, even if you generate ipa of your app and distribute it via Diawi, the other person won't be able to install it, so there's no way to achieve what you want. You can visit [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/) to see more details about different membership programs and features provided by them.